# Mac Automator - merge pdfs, change filename of original pdfs, and save new pdf in same folder with name of pdf 1

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript, osx-yosemite, automator

Mac Yosemite 10.10.2.  Suppose I have two pdfs, myPdf1.pdf and myPdf2.pdf, located in /myFolder.  I want a service or script that does the following:

1. Renames the original pdfs to _MERGED_myPdf1.pdf and _MERGED_myPdf2.pdf
2. Creates and saves the new merged pdf as /myFolder/myPdf1.pdf

I have tried numerous workarounds with no avail.  I started here [Mac Automator - Combine PDF files, save in same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087228/mac-automator-combine-pdf-files-save-in-same-folder)

My problem is with the final step: Move Finder Items to containerPath.  My merged pdf is moved to the desktop instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround using AppleScript, which can be tied into an Automator service or app.  Instead of renaming the input pdfs, I'm moving them to a folder.

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Finder"
    set trashFolder to "MacHD:path:to:some:folder"
    set outputFolder to container of (item 1 of input)
    set outputName to name of (item 1 of input)
    set outputFile to (outputFolder as text) & outputName
    repeat with p in input
        move p to trashFolder with replacing
    end repeat
    set pdfFiles to ""
    repeat with p in input
        set pdfFiles to pdfFiles & " " & quoted form of POSIX path of p
    end repeat
    --display dialog outputFile
    --display dialog pdfFiles       
    do shell script "/System/Library/Automator/Combine\\ PDF\\ Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py " & "-o " & quoted form of POSIX path of outputFile & pdfFiles
    return outputFile as alias
end tell
```

end run