# Automator Quick Action to Save Images into Same Folder

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript, jpeg, automator

I'm trying to make an Automator Quick action (Mac OS) that will save images from pdf pages **into the same folder where the pdf is located**.

**Edit: user3439894 wrote that I should have and did not make totally clear that I want "to send multiple files to the Quick Action from different folders and have the files created in each respective folder the file is in"

I found that it's easy to have files saved to a particular folder; for example, here's a workflow that saves images from a pdf to the desktop:
[image]

The hard part is saving to the same folder where the pdf is located. I tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087228/mac-automator-combine-pdf-files-save-in-same-folder), but I get: "Rename Finder Items: Name Single Item" encountered an error: "More than one Finder item was passed to Name Single Item". I don't know how to fix that -- the whole point of my task is to output multiple images from the .pdf.

There are actually 2 workflows shown on [the stackoverflow page I mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087228/mac-automator-combine-pdf-files-save-in-same-folder).  I tried adapting both of them and they both gave the same error.  Below is one of my adaptions. The "Get Specified Finder Items" action is just for testing purposes.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see a couple of differences in your workflow from what I posted as an answer which I can reassure you works just fine and doesn't save the files to the desktop. If you want to convert it to a Quick Action (which I've just done and it works fine too), you should get rid of "Ask for Finder Items" action since you'll call it directly by right clicking on the target PDF. Don't test it in Automator. Save it and directly deploy it from Finder. Second, don't type "pdf-name" in the Rename Finder Items' "new name" field. Drag the variable called "pdf-name" from the bottom and drop it in the field.

Comment: This is doable if you take a different approach, by using _shell scripting_ in a **Run Shell Script** _action_. I have tested several different ways to achieve the goal using native utilities and or a combination of native and or third-party utilities, depending on what your actual needs/wants are besides being able to process _files_ from different _folders_ sent at the same time with the output going to their respective _folders_.

Comment: The big hurdle is that the **Render PDF Pages as Images** action outputs to a temporary folder, so for each individual PDF you would need to save the containing folder, render the images, rename and move those images from the temporary folder (avoiding any duplicate names), then proceed with the next file item.  To use that particular action you would need to step through the input items individually (using the `Dispense Items Incrementally` action, for example), or do the whole thing using a **Run Shell Script** or **Run AppleScript** action and just use Automator to feed it the file items.

Answer (score 1):

This gets a bit convoluted because Automator doesn’t have a default action to get names or paths (that was one of my first actions back in the day), you need to shuffle stuff around while you work at getting items into variables, and workflows handle multiple input items as a single batch.

The **Rename Finder Items** action will only rename (you need to use the **Make Sequential** option rather than **Name Single Item**), but that doesn’t help much, especially since the **Render PDF Pages as Images** action also uses sequential numbers in its output.

For items with the same parent folder (otherwise a third party action would need to be used to handle the items individually), a **Run AppleScript** action can be used (as in your linked examples) to get the parent folder for use in a variable, so your workflow would be something like:

- Workflow receives PDF files in any application
- Set Value of Variable { Variable: *input*}
- Run AppleScript:

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder" to return (container of first item of input) as alias
  end run
  ```
- Set Value of Variable { Variable: *folder* }
- Get Value of Variable { Variable: *input* }  (Ignore input)
- Render PDF Pages as Images
- Copy Finder Items { To: *folder* }  (select or drag folder variable to combobox field)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think when you say "(otherwise a third party action would need to be used..." you're saying that the solution you've outlined would not apply unless all items are in the same parent folder. But if so, that restricted case is of little interest to me. I want to be able to use Spotlight to find .pdf's located across multiple folders, select them, right click, and use the Quick Action to output .jpgs to all those multiple folders. Unfortunately, your response is consistent with what I've found in trying to solve this problem, and I'm beginning to conclude it just can't be done

Comment: Take a look at the [Dispense Items Incrementally](http://automator.us/leopard/downloads/index.html) action - it will loop through the input items one at a time.  Place the action at the beginning of the workflow and a Loop action at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way that works for me.

- Workflow receives PDF files in any application
- Set Value of Variable {Variable: InputPDFs}
- Run AppleScript:

  ```
  on run {InputPDFs, parameters}
      tell application "Finder" to return (container of first item of InputPDFs) as alias
  end run
  ```
- Set Value of Variable {Variable: PathToPDFs}
- Get Value of Variable {Variable: InputPDFs} (Ignore input)
- Render PDF Pages as Images
- Set Value of Variable {Variable: InputPDFs}
- Get Value of Variable {Variable: InputPDFs} (Ignore input)
- Rename Finder Items: Make Sequential
- Set Value of Variable {Variable: InputPDFs}
- Move Finder Items {To: PathToPDFs}

Comment: This solution does not work. The key goal of my original question was to "make an Automator Quick action (Mac OS) that will save images from pdf pages into the same folder where the pdf is located." I tried your code and found that it saved all files onto the desktop rather than the original folder. As stated in the original question, I already knew how to do that. To make sure I was doing exactly what you said I made a video showing the code & running it. I left a link to that video in a comment for 3 months but there was no response. I've now deleted my comment and stopped hosting that video

Comment: This solution looks similar to mine and it looks correct as well. I think @TonyM the issue is on your side but it's hard to tell what without knowing your system configurations and what exactly you may be doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution in the screenshot works fine in Catalina (10.15.7).

1. It prompts you to select the input PDF (you can replace that with your preferred input method).
2. It stores the full path including the input file name ("PDF-file"), the full path excluding the input file name ("pdfPath") and the base input file name without path and extension ("pdf-name").
3. Renders PDF to images
4. Renames each image as pdf-name-*** (note: If you skipped renaming or used "Add number to existing item name", you would end up with the automatic indexing added by the Render PDF as images widget which won't start with 01 but rather number-of-pages + 1 eg. 66, 67, 68, etc. if your pdf has 65 pages).
5. Save images to the original input folder (same folder where the selected PDF is located).

[image]

Comment: This solution did not work for me. As I wrote in the original post, "The hard part is saving to the same folder where the pdf is located." See the end of my post where I show a screenshot of my attempt. Note that I'm trying to run it as a service so that I can simply right click pdfs in any folder. Nevertheless (unless I made a mistake) I implemented everything else just as posted here and navigated to the file when asked. Unfortunately, all the files ended up on the desktop rather than the folder containing the pdf.

Comment: I see the solution you claim to be my solution but you seemed to have altered it and it's not what I suggested. See my comment on your post. I've also converted my solution to a Quick Action and that works too, the images get saved to the same folder where the pdf is located, not the desktop. I think you may have some issue with your computer because everyone uses this code in my company without a problem. Or perhaps you haven't tried to actually save it as a Quick Action and run it from Finder by right clicking on the target PDF (the workflow you've posted in Edit can't be run from Automator)

Comment: See his comment to the answer by red_menace. While your _workflow_ works for you as intended it cannot and will not work as is for how Tony M intends to use it. He wants to send multiple files to the _Quick Action_ from different _folders_ and have the _files_ created in each respective _folder_ the file is in.  Your _workflow_ gets the _container_ of the first _item_ passed and when the next _item_ in the _list_ gets processed its output is sent to the wrong _folder_.  This was not made totally clear in his OP and it should have.

Comment: Let's not say "it wasn't clear" when you really mean it wasn't even mentioned at all in the question. Anyone can view the edit history and see that the requirement to have PDF files from different folders was simply not included at the time I answered this question, he added it later. OP should have more respect for the community spending time on his questions and shouldn't keep changing the question and then downvote answers that were correct in the original context.